# Reset recoil state when navigate to new page

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, recoiljs

When `Link` is clicked, how can initialize state, of `recoil`, be triggered to reset counter?

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import { atom, useRecoilState, RecoilRoot } from "recoil";

const counterState = atom({
  key: "counterState",
  default: null
});

const CustomComponent = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useRecoilState(counterState);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Add 1</button>

      <h2>Counter: {counter}</h2>
    </>
  );
};

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot
      initializeState={({ set }) => {
        set(counterState, 0); // set counter to 0 as default
      }}
    >
      <CustomComponent />

      <Link href="/">Go to the page and reset counter</Link>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-recoil-reload-reset-state-psjuuo)

### Steps to reproduce

- Increment at least 1 time
- Click link to navigate to page (I used same page)

### Expect

Counter is 0 (same as initial value)

### Actual

Counter is not 0

Comment: does this help? -> https://codesandbox.io/s/next-recoil-reload-reset-state-forked-ugfvh8?file=/pages/index.js:0-830

I will post it as a answer later on

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works, but I need to reuse the logic (if it's possible) of initializeState without repeating the code.

Comment: Basically, I need to use context of loaded page (RecoilRoot) before CustomComponent is loaded.

Comment: From RecoilRoot [doc](https://recoiljs.org/docs/api-reference/core/RecoilRoot) of _initializeState_: "This sets up the state for the initial render and is not intended for subsequent state changes or async initialization.".
I want reinitialize after first render (RecoilRoot must be removed).

Comment: Related [example](https://github.com/facebookexperimental/Recoil/issues/958#issuecomment-1117978957).

Comment: Fixed adding `key` in RecoilRoot.

Comment: Could you please share your solution?

Comment: [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/next-recoil-reload-reset-state-fixed-0lppqj?file=/pages/index.js)
If the _key_ is different, the component will change (new render).